# Java swing : warning ComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I created a bunch of collection like this :

```
Collection<JTextField> myJTextfield = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
Collection<JComboBox> myJComboBox = new ArrayList<JComboBox>();
Collection<JLabel> myJLabel = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
```

and I'm getting a warning only in the JComboBox collection which it says:

**ComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox should be parameterized**

I looked for what it means in google, they talk about generic types but I still don't get it really. my questions are :

- what does it means?
- why the warning appears only for the JComboBox collection??
- how can I remove it?

  I'll appreciate any explanation.

Comment: `JComboBox` can accept generics

Comment: @MadProgrammer     can you explain more? I dont understand the generic type ... i'm creating a collection of type JComboBox .. where is the generic type here ?  what is a  raw type?? and what about parameter ??

Comment: I'm guessing, as I don't get the warning, but because `JComboBox` can accept generics, you `myJComboBox` can contain any type `JComboBox`.  The compiler can not guarantee the type of `JComboBox` which might be added or retrieved from the collection

Comment: @MadProgrammer well I added this Collection<JComboBox<String>> myJComboBox = new ArrayList<JComboBox<String>>(); I specified thye type think I got what do you mean :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer so I can't add another type of JComboBox  which is an integer to the same collection??

Comment: @MadProgrammer  i men if I've a multiple protected JComboBox<String> typeAlgo; and protected JComboBox<Integer> typeAlgo; and i want to do a same action on them like make them not visible , i've to create 2 collection ?? one for type JComboBox<String>  and another for type  JComboBox<Integer>???

Comment: It depends, if you don't care about the data type, you might be able to use JComboBox<?>

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok good :)

Answer (score 1):

`JComboBox` is a generic class. You should modify it to be something like:

```
Collection<JComboBox<String>> myJComboBox = new ArrayList<JComboBox<String>>();
```